# 500 internal server error instead of 302 redirect- JMeter

Tags: cookies, jmeter, httpcookie, blazemeter

I'm trying to investigate the issue as I mentioned in the subject.

I login to the application and successfully able to land on the home page of my application through my JMeter code.

When I click on "user details" tab , I should be redirected 2 times.

Successfully able to redirect for the first time. For the second redirection I'm getting 500 error code instead of 302 again.

URL for "User details" is a plain URL, doesn't come with any need of correlation.

I have cookie manager with "standard"( tried all other options also on cookie manager)

I see that - cookie value `SameSite=None;` is also seen at request body along with other values only during the reply of my script(I do not see this in the recorded traffic/even if I cross verify using fiddler).

Would like to know if this can be a problematic. If so how can I remove this.

Answer (score 0):

Try playing with `Redirect Automatically` and `Follow Redirects` boxes in the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler

[image]

if it doesn't help - be aware that you can extract the redirect URL from the [Location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Location) header using [Regular Expression Extractor](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)

If you think that the problem is with the cookie you can enable debug logging for the [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation:

```
<Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control" level="debug" />
```

this way you will be able to see what's going on under the hood in [jmeter.log](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) file as it might be the case that the cookie is broken somehow (expired, wrong path, etc.)

Comment: thanks for your response @Dmitri T. 
Ill check acc. your suggestions.

Would like to know if SameSite=None expected at request body(cookie).
I thought we see this at only Set-cookie*usually happens at response.